# TurnContext in microsoft bot builder is giving error when fetching data from WebSocket server

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, botframework, azure-bot-service

I want to show the response coming from WebSocket server to emulator that is Microsoft Bot Builder but I am having a issue that inside ws.addEventListener. Here is the code

```
ws.addEventListener('message',async function (event) {
                const msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
                if(msg.topic === 'aws/chat' && msg.contentType === 'application/json'){
                    const content = JSON.parse(msg.content);
                    switch(content.Type){
                        case 'MESSAGE':
                            try{
                                  if(content.ParticipantRole !== 'CUSTOMER'){
                                    responseMessage = `${content.DisplayName} : ${content.Content}`;
                                    console.log(`responseMessage :- ${responseMessage}`);
                                    await turnContext.sendActivity(responseMessage);
                                }
                            }catch(error){
                                console.log("Insise Error");
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Event':
                            if(content.ContentType.includes('ended')){
                                responseMessage = `Chat ended`;
                            }
                    }
                }
            });
```

When I debugged **await turnContext.sendActivity(responseMessage)** is loosing scope inside the listener function and not able to return the response to the emulator.

From WS server receiving response and getting printed in console with error.

> responseMessage :- BOT : To speak to an agent, press or say #
> Insise Error
> TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked
> at WebSocket. (D:\azure-bot\echo-bot\bots\stateManagementBot.js:155:59)

Here is the full code of stateManagementBot.js

```
// The accessor names for the conversation data and user profile state property accessors.
const CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY = 'conversationData';
const USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY = 'userProfile';

let responseMessage;
let connectionToken;
let ws;

class StateManagementBot extends ActivityHandler {
    constructor(conversationState, userState) {
        super();
    // Create the state property accessors for the conversation data and user profile.
    this.conversationDataAccessor = conversationState.createProperty(CONVERSATION_DATA_PROPERTY);
    this.userProfileAccessor = userState.createProperty(USER_PROFILE_PROPERTY);

    // The state management objects for the conversation and user state.
    this.conversationState = conversationState;
    this.userState = userState;

    this.onMessage(async (turnContext, next) => {
        // Get the state properties from the turn context.
        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.await next()
        
        if(turnContext.activity.text === '#'){
            const url = await this.connectToAgent(turnContext.activity.text);
            const initialMessage = {
                topic: "aws/subscribe",
                content: {
                topics: ["aws/chat"]
                }
            };
            console.log(url[1]);
            ws = new WebSocket(url[1]);
            console.log('Before Websocket....');
            ws.addEventListener("open", () => {
                console.log('Websocket....');
                ws.send(JSON.stringify(initialMessage));
            });
            console.log("Websocket Conn...");
            const param = {
                ConnectionToken: connectionToken, /* required */
                Content: turnContext.activity.text, /* required */
                ContentType: 'text/plain', /* required */
            };
            connectparticipant.sendMessage(param, function(err, data) {
                console.log('Sending....');
                if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
                else     console.log(data);           // successful response
            });

            ws.addEventListener('message',async function (event) {
                const msg = JSON.parse(event.data);
                if(msg.topic === 'aws/chat' && msg.contentType === 'application/json'){
                    const content = JSON.parse(msg.content);
                    switch(content.Type){
                        case 'MESSAGE':
                            try{
                                  if(content.ParticipantRole !== 'CUSTOMER'){
                                    responseMessage = `${content.DisplayName} : ${content.Content}`;
                                    console.log(`responseMessage :- ${responseMessage}`);
                                    await turnContext.sendActivity(responseMessage);
                                }
                            }catch(error){
                                console.log("Insise Error");
                                console.log(error);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 'Event':
                            if(content.ContentType.includes('ended')){
                                responseMessage = `Chat ended`;
                            }
                    }
                }
            });
            
        }
        // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
        await next();
    });
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BotFramework TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73076334/botframework-typeerror-cannot-perform-get-on-a-proxy-that-has-been-revoked)

Comment: @DeepDave-MT I want scope of turnContext that needs to be under ws.addEventListener('message',async function (event) {.....}.

Comment: Please clarify.

Comment: @AP01 Sir, I am connecting BOT to AWS Connect CCP in case BOT is not able to answer A call to agent will be made and the user will be able to chat with the agent.
So for that I am making a connection through websockets and inside  ws.addEventListener('message') function will receive the chat from the agent that I want to show to the bot (emulator) I am consoling it and message is received but when I am using await turnContext.sendActivity(responseMsg) it is not working. I debugged it and found out that turnContext is not in the scope.

Comment: It doesn't seem like your event listener was actually given your turnContext. Perhaps you could try getting back a response from AWS Connect CCP, storing it in a variable (outside the event listener), and then calling `turnContext.SendActivity(Variable)`

Comment: Yeah I did but it doesn't work instantly we need to give response at the time of websocket server receives a message. If I save it in a variable and use turnContext it will work after user send a message. I hope you understand.

Comment: Then try passing the turn context to the event listener.

Comment: Did that also not working, even I declared a global variable like testTurnContext = turnContext and passed it inside a eventListener and when debugged found that after the WS server is started testTurnContext contains no object with proxy revoked : true

Comment: Why can you not exit out of the event listener as soon as you receive a response, and then send that to the user?

Comment: that only happens when the user will send a message again then turnContext outside of ws.adEventListener will work and will return the response, it wont happen on the spot like a live chat.