# BotFramework TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked

Tags: node.js, botframework, typeerror, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

I am trying to develop a MS Teams bot that sends content to students module(unit) wise. I have created 3 classes:

1. methods.js = Contains all the methods for sending texts, attachments etc.
2. teamBot.js = Captures a specific keyword from the users and based on that executes a function.
3. test.js = Connects the bot with Airtable and sends the content accordingly

I am facing `Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked` error. I figured it might be because of the context. I am passing context as a parameter, which I feel might not be the correct way, how can I achieve the result, and retain the context between files.

teamsBot.js

```
const test = require("./test");
class TeamsBot extends TeamsActivityHandler {
  constructor() {
    super();

    // record the likeCount
    this.likeCountObj = { likeCount: 0 };

    this.onMessage(async (context, next) => {
      console.log("Running with Message Activity.");
      let txt = context.activity.text;
      // const removedMentionText = TurnContext.removeRecipientMention(context.activity);
      // if (removedMentionText) {
      //   // Remove the line break
      //   txt = removedMentionText.toLowerCase().replace(/\n|\r/g, "").trim();
      // }

      // Trigger command by IM text
      switch (txt) {
        case "Begin": {
         await test.sendModuleContent(context)
        }
 

      // By calling next() you ensure that the next BotHandler is run.
      await next();
    });

    // Listen to MembersAdded event, view https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/bot-v3/bots-notifications for more events
    this.onMembersAdded(async (context, next) => {
      const membersAdded = context.activity.membersAdded;
      for (let cnt = 0; cnt < membersAdded.length; cnt++) {
        if (membersAdded[cnt].id) {
          const card = cardTools.AdaptiveCards.declareWithoutData(rawWelcomeCard).render();
          await context.sendActivity({ attachments: [CardFactory.adaptiveCard(card)] });
          break;
        }
      }
      await next();
    });
  }
```

test.js

```
const ms = require('./methods')
async function sendModuleContent(context) {
 data = module_text //fetched from Airtable
await ms.sendText(context, data)
}
```

methods.js

```
const {TeamsActivityHandler, ActivityHandler, MessageFactory } = require('botbuilder');


async function sendText(context, text){
    console.log("Sending text")
    await context.sendActivity(text);

}
```

Comment: Could you please share the sample or reference doc if any which you are referring?

Comment: I am referring to this particular repository - https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-overview?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer this: [TypeError: Cannot perform 'get' on a proxy that has been revoked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62259653/typeerror-cannot-perform-get-on-a-proxy-that-has-been-revoked)

make the following changes to test.js

```
const {
    TurnContext
} = require("botbuilder");

var conversationReferences = {};
var adapter;

async function sendModuleContent(context) {
    data = module_text //fetched from Airtable

    const currentUser = context.activity.from.id;

    conversationReferences[currentUser] = TurnContext.getConversationReference(context.activity);

    adapter = context.adapter;
    await adapter.continueConversation(conversationReferences[currentUser], async turnContext => {
        await turnContext.sendActivity(data);
    });
}
```

Comment: Error Fixed!, Thank you!.